# Windows C++ API list view not showing

Tags: c++, windows, api, listview

I'm currently learning the Windows API for C++, and I'm trying to create a ListView control. I edited the source from MSDN documentation, but I'm stuck cause no list view actually shows in my window. When I create different controls they are shown without problems. I use this function to create the ListView.

```
HWND CreateListView(HWND hwndParent)
{
    INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX icex;           
    icex.dwICC = ICC_LISTVIEW_CLASSES;
    icex.dwSize = sizeof(icex);
    if(InitCommonControlsEx(&icex) == FALSE) MessageBox(NULL,L"Initiation of common controls failed",L"Fail", MB_OK);

    RECT rcClient;                       

    GetClientRect(hwndParent, &rcClient);


    HWND hWndListView = CreateWindow(WC_LISTVIEW,
    L"",
    WS_CHILD | LVS_REPORT | LVS_EDITLABELS,
    0, 0,
    rcClient.right - rcClient.left,
    rcClient.bottom - rcClient.top,
    hwndParent,
    (HMENU)IDM_DATABAZA_LIST,
    hInst,
    NULL);

    return (hWndListView);
}
```

The list view is created without problems,but it doesn't show in the window. What might be the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `WS_VISIBLE` flag:

```
HWND hWndListView = CreateWindow(WC_LISTVIEW, L"", 
    WS_VISIBLE|WS_CHILD|LVS_REPORT|LVS_EDITLABELS,...)
```

Or use `ShowWindow(hWndListView, SW_SHOW)` or `SetWindowPos(hWndListView,...,SWP_NOZORDER|SWP_SHOWWINDOW);`

And add error check

```
if (!hWndListView)
{
    OutputDebugStringW(L"error\n");
    return NULL;
}
```